# Using Binary Image Classification on Video

Tags: keras, image-classification

Using tensorflow/Keras, I have built a good model which is currently binary classification.  For example, training labels would be images of a person's knees bent or knees not bent.

The idea behind such a model could be using a continuous video feed, and when it detects either knees bent or not, a certain probability would output.  It works, however, since it's binary, I have probabilities close to 0 or 1 even though a person is not even in the video feed.

Any ideas on how I can change my model (perhaps multi-class) in over a continuous feed - which could be hundreds of images over a minute would only give me probabilities for those events of knees bent or not?  If going multi-class, would I then have to also train all other potential images?  That seems close to impossible, even with using transfer learning with ImageNet.  Any suggestions?

Comment: If you have enough computational power, you can do a binary classification (person present vs person not present). When it's present, do your other model for knees bent vs not bent

Answer (score 1):

**Using a multi-class network would probably be the most efficient approach.**

Training two networks (as suggested in the comments: one network to detect the presence of a person and one to detect the state of the knee) is unnecessary and overly complex.  You can train the network on three classes: bent knee, straight knee, absent knee.  For the absent knee, **you do not need to train on *all* possible images, just images you expect to see.**  For instance, these negative data could be the background of your intended images; take a picture with the knee and one without.

If speed is a major requirement, the model architecture becomes critical.  I suggest exploring [MobileNets](https://arxiv.org/abs/1704.04861) as they are quite fast and do not sacrifice too much accuracy.